# Add Format of 2 decimal places to IIF Expression?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I need to take this expression:

```
=IIf(Count(Fields!counter.Value) > 0, 1 - Sum(Fields!validatedErrors.Value) / Count(Fields!counter.Value), 0)
```

and add 2 decimal places to it. I am not sure how to though

I know I can add

```
=Format(Fields!CUL1.Value,"F2")
```

Which should tack on the extra 2 decimal places in a normal value. The IIF is throwing me off though.

I expected to be able to do something like this:

```
=IIf(Count(Fields!counter.Value) > 0, 1 - Format(Sum(Fields!validatedErrors.Value) / Count(Fields!counter.Value), 0),"F2")
```

Fields!validatedErrors.Value = 1352

Count(Fields!counter.Value), 0) = 1620

1352 / 1620 = .8345

Right now it is returning 83% which is fine, but I want to change it to return 83.45%

I have also tried:

```
=IIf(Sum(Fields!DestElectronic.Value) > 0, Format(Sum(IIf(Fields!DestElectronic.Value = 1, 1, 0)) /Count(Fields!counter.Value), 0),"#0.00")
```

and

```
=IIf(Sum(Fields!DestElectronic.Value) > 0, Format(Sum(IIf(Fields!DestElectronic.Value = 1, 1, 0)) /Count(Fields!counter.Value), 0),"#0.##")
```

Comment: just change the format property of the output cell/textbox to "p2" then 0.8345 will be formatted as 83.45% wihtout doing anything else. There is no need to format this in the expression.

Comment: Holy crap. I am not a smart man. Thank you.

Comment: no problem, if only all things were as simple !

Comment: Try to set the format of the TextBox to 0.00% so the format will kept when exporting to something like Excel.